# Window rolls back down automatically Prius 2010

Tags: toyota, power-windows, prius

When I roll up the rear right power window it reaches the top and immediately rolls back down and stops 2" or so from the bottom.

There are no obstructions in the window frame or anything blocking it's motion.

The battery was low and we had to jump start it and the problem started after the jump start.

Answer (score 6):

You need to have your auto-up/down feature reset. It's actually a pretty easy procedure:

1. From the driver's seat, push and hold the offending window's down button. Keep pressing it while the window is going down. Hold the button in place (down) for at least 5 seconds after the window is down all the way.
2. Pull and hold the same switch up to bring the window all the way. Continue to pull the button up for at least 5 seconds after the window is up all the way.

**NOTE:** If the window will not go up and stay up while pulling on the switch, you may need to tap the switch until it gets to the top, at which point you'd continue to hold the button to get the calibration done.

Should be good to go.

Comment: Curious how this jump start only affected one window of the four.

Comment: As I understand it, a low/dead battery can cause random ECU programming to be lost, although I'm guessing it's not supposed to lose programming, since that would be frustrating to have to reset all the windows if the battery ever died.  Just random that the right rear calibration was lost this time.

Comment: It could also just be coincidence or was on the verge of being out of calibration. Stupid things happen for stupid reasons, but thankfully there's a fix for it. What I've seen more often than what the OP described is when the window won't go all the way up.  It kind of sucks to always run around with 2" of open window in your vehicle, lol.

Comment: In my case, step #2 did not work.  The window would automatically lower when it hit the top, even if I held the up button.  I had to raise the window by tapping the up button until the window was seated at the top, and then I was able to hold it for 5 seconds to set the calibration.  I tried to edit this into the answer but it was rejected.

Comment: @ChrisVesper - Does that edit cover what you're talking about? My apologies for rejecting your edit, as it wasn't making sense to me. Your comment made a lot more sense.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Sure, that covers it.  I saw that procedure on youtube, reddit, toyota forums, dealer web sites, etc. to fix the window issue. I tried it before posting, but it didn't work of course.  I just wanted this SE answer to be more correct than the other sources.